# Angular Noob: $resource is not returning the record?

Tags: angularjs

I'm on Rails + Angular. I created a route in rails

`http://localhost:3000/api/products/30` that returns JSON:

```
{"id":30,"name":"blue / red / sky blue square eyeglasses","active":true,"page_title":"","meta_description":"","created_at":"2014-05-27T20:26:03.000Z","updated_at":"2014-07-25T14:42:19.000Z","vendor_id":4,"short_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum do","long_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum do","shape_id":4,"material_id":1,"category_id":3,"taxable":false,"products_colors":[{"id":31,"color_id":4,"product_id":30,"mens":true,"womens":true,"created_at":"2014-05-27T20:26:03.000Z","updated_at":"2014-05-28T19:05:13.000Z","mens_sort_order":1,"womens_sort_order":0,"color":{"id":4,"name":"sky blue","created_at":"2014-05-16T18:11:03.000Z","updated_at":"2014-05-16T18:11:03.000Z","image":{"url":"/images/no-image.png"}}},{"id":36,"color_id":1,"product_id":30,"mens":true,"womens":true,"created_at":"2014-05-28T20:19:40.000Z","updated_at":"2014-05-28T20:19:40.000Z","mens_sort_order":null,"womens_sort_order":null,"color":{"id":1,"name":"blue","created_at":"2014-05-16T17:01:26.000Z","updated_at":"2014-07-25T18:49:54.000Z","image":{"url":"/uploads/color/1/blackt.jpg"}}},{"id":37,"color_id":3,"product_id":30,"mens":false,"womens":true,"created_at":"2014-05-28T20:20:15.000Z","updated_at":"2014-05-28T20:20:15.000Z","mens_sort_order":null,"womens_sort_order":null,"color":{"id":3,"name":"red","created_at":"2014-05-16T18:10:25.000Z","updated_at":"2014-07-25T18:59:17.000Z","image":{"url":"/images/no-image.png"}}},{"id":38,"color_id":5,"product_id":30,"mens":true,"womens":true,"created_at":"2014-05-28T20:21:58.000Z","updated_at":"2014-05-28T20:21:58.000Z","mens_sort_order":null,"womens_sort_order":null,"color":{"id":5,"name":"pitch black","created_at":"2014-05-22T18:04:25.000Z","updated_at":"2014-05-22T18:04:25.000Z","image":{"url":"/images/no-image.png"}}}]}
```

However, when I try to retrieve this JSON in angular by using $resource, it's returning a `Resource`:

provider (should I be using a provider?):

```
app.provider("SingleProduct", function() {
  this.$get = ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
      find: function(path) {
        var Product = $resource("/api" + path);
        return Product;
      }
    }
  }];
});
```

controller:

```
app.controller('ProductCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$resource', 'SingleProduct', function($scope, $location, $resource, SingleProduct) {

  // $location.path is equal to /products/30
  var product = SingleProduct.find($location.path());
  $scope.title = "fff";
  $scope.product = product;
}]);
```

view:

```
<div ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
  {{ title }} // prints out fff (CORRECT)
  {{ product.name }} // prints out Resource (INCORRECT, should be "blue / red ...")
</div>
```

What's going on ? This technique worked when I did it for `/api/products` where it returned an array of products in JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually call any method on the resource. Your `.find` returns a resource object with a specified path, now do something with said resource:

```
var product = SingleProduct.find($location.path());
var products = product.get(); //something like this
```